# How to include src/test/java beans to any <name>Test.java using spring boot way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I gave under src/test/java these 2 classes

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {

@Autowired
private Example example;

   @Test
   public void getTwoTest() {

       assertEquals(new Integer(2), example.getTwo());
   }

}

@TestComponent
public class Example {

   public Integer getTwo(){
       return 2;
   }

}
```

I read the docs, but still have many questions. When i click to "Run as Junit Test" it gets an error because can't autowire my bean "Example". How do i say to spring boot to look for beans inside src/test/java too? My second Question is how do i say to use another application.properties, exclusive for tests?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaDoc for [@TestComponent](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestComponent.html) it says the following:

"@Component that can be used when a bean is intended only for tests, and should be excluded from Spring Boot's component scanning."

So, Example is not going to be wired. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by testing another test class. Maybe try placing Example under src/main/java and annotate it with @Component?

As for test specific properties, check out the docs for [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html). This let's you override properties with new values in line or from a seperate file.

Comment: I have a TestDataBuilder that is on a package inside src/test/java that i need to autowire...

Comment: Do you definitely need to Autowire it? What are you testing inside TestDataBuilder? Is it possible to instantiate it directly (as @JeanValjean suggests) in the test via new TestDataBuilder()?

Comment: Well, yeah i can do that. But how can i make ExampleTest, have all the beans inside src/test/java and src/main/java?

Comment: @GunterAmorim I think you are doing a little mess there. Is it an open source porject in which we could have a look? Spring makes like very easy, when you know how to use it :)

Comment: Yep, I agree with @JeanValjean. It's difficult to say exactly way you need to do here because wiring a test class into another test class is a pretty unusual thing to do. [This link](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) covers approaches to testing pretty thoroughly. If you're testing the logic of a class (like your Example class), generally you don't need to autowire it. Just instatiate it as per usual. If that bean has autowired dependecies too, thats fine: this is why it's best to autowire on constructors so you can pass in mock versions of dependecies.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a `Configuration` class and create the beans there

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ExampleTest.Config.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {

  @Autowired
  private Example example;

   @Test
   public void getTwoTest() {

       assertEquals(new Integer(2), example.getTwo());
   }

    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package"})
    public static Config {
        @Bean
        public Example example() {
            return new Example();
        }
    }

}
```

Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42113571/1339429) answer says the right thing about the annotation. You should not create the bean like that, or create the bean in the main app and use that annotation to filter the bean out from the application context. Same goes for classes annotated with `@TestConfiguration`.

Finally, if you do not need a context (i.e. you have a unit test), you do not need at all to autowire beans and you can use `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean`.

Comment: I have a TestDataBuilder that is on a package inside src/test/java that i need to autowire...

Comment: @GunterAmorim yeah, just show us what do you have there. Do you need is as a bean? Just return it in the Config class as shown. Do you autowire beans? Then use the Config again to pass the beans via constructor.